# How do I make my custom function return an error message if one of the vector elements has NA or is not an integer in R?

Tags: r, function, integer, warnings, na

What I want to do is a function where x is a vector, and y any integer. If y is inside the vector x, then it should return "TRUE". Also, if the vector contains NAs or decimals, then it should print an error message.

So far I have created this, but if I input `search(c(9,8,3,NA),3)` it gives me this message:

```
Warning message:
In if (x%%1 != 0 | anyNA(x) == TRUE) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

If if input a vector with a decimal in it like this `search(c(8,9,7.01,12),12)`it won't give an ERROR message.

This is my code so far:

```
search <- function(x,y){
  if (x%%1!=0 | anyNA(x)==TRUE){
    print("ERROR")
  }else{
    if(y %in% x){
      print(TRUE)
    }
    else
      print(FALSE)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your function to produce an error, use `stop`, not `print`. Any program that relies on the output of the function will otherwise keep running, without noticing anything is wrong. This could make things very hard to debug later. `stop` throws an error, which can then be handled appropriately. Also, because the function will exit if the condition is met, you don't need an `else` afterwards: that code will only ever run if the condition isn't met, so the `else` is redundant.

You can also simplify some of the logic. You don't need `if(condition == TRUE)`, since `if(condition)` does the same thing. Finally, the construction `if(condition){ print(TRUE) } else { print(FALSE) }` is logically identical to `print(condition)`

```r
search <- function(x, y){
  if (any(x %% 1 != 0) | anyNA(x) | length(y) != 1) stop("Error")
  y %in% x
}
```

Now try it on test cases:

```
search(c(1, 3, 5), 3)
#> [1] TRUE
search(c(1, 3, 5), 2)
#> [1] FALSE
search(c(1, 3, NA), 3)
#> Error in search(c(1, 3, NA), 3): Error
search(c(1, 3, 5.1), 3)
#> Error in search(c(1, 3, 5.1), 3): Error
search(c(1, 3, 5), c(1, 3))
#> Error in search(c(1, 3, 5), c(1, 3)): Error
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I wasn't aware of the stop function. I really love this solution because it's more simplified and it needs less loops.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sum(x %% 1) > 0` to validate `x`.

```
search <- function(x,y){
     if (sum(x %% 1) | anyNA(x)==TRUE){
          stop("ERROR")
     }else{
          if(y %in% x){
               print(TRUE)
          }
          else
               print(FALSE)
     }
}
```

...and the output:

```
> search(c(9,8,3,NA),3)
Error in search(c(9, 8, 3, NA), 3) : ERROR

> search(c(9,8,3),3)
[1] TRUE
>
> search(c(9,8,3),13)
[1] FALSE
>
```

Also, it's good practice to use the `stop()` function to communicate an error within an R function. `stop()` stops execution of the current expression and executes an error action.

Comment: Surprisingly, this won't work. Try `is.integer(c(1, 3, 5))` and compare to `is.integer(as.integer(c(1, 3, 5)))`

Comment: @AllanCameron -  Fixed it to sum the modulus operator instead. On testing I noticed that the vectors specified as `c(3,5,4)` come in as numeric, not integers.

Comment: Thank you also for this. Even if this one isn't short, at least I can see what exactly did wrong with my code. Thank you also for the feedback I'm new to R and programming in general.

Comment: @lalalallala - No problem. One of the interesting things about R is that there are often many ways to do a particular thing, and sometimes the functions don't work exactly as expected, as evidenced between the interaction between @AllanCameron and me in the comments. I originally posted an answer after my first test produced the desired result, but additional test cases showed that my original solution with `is.integer()` wasn't working as expected. I updated it to an alternative `sum(x %% 1) > 0` so the `if()` function would evaluate to a single TRUE / FALSE statement.